# Is there work on differential Galois theory and infinite operators?

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations, galois-theory, differential-galois-theory

I'm curious about differential Galois theory and I've noticed that everything I read covers only finite order operators (e.g. $L = Y^n + a_{n-1} Y^{n-1} + \dots + a_0 Y$). Has there been any work on using differential Galois theory to instead study infinite operators?

Answer (score 2):

The March 2010 paper by Bernard Malgrange, *Pseudogroupes de Lie et théorie de Galois différentielle*, IHES/M/10/11 https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00469778 covers this case, I believe.

Comment: Sadly, Malgrange passed away a few days ago.

Comment: @M.G. Sad news indeed.  A relevant lecture for us to remember him by: https://youtu.be/EWQJx1RxiBw?si=ErclEiulcn6_zspT